# Add the plus symbol with the bounty score in the revision history

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bounties, revisions-list

I see the bounty score with the **+** (plus symbol) in the [Featured tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/?tab=featured) and the bounty offered post itself. Like the below:

[image: Featured Tab]

---

[image: Bounty notice in the post]

But the **+** (plus symbol) is not added in the [revision history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/291231/revisions)

[image: Bounty notice in the revision history]

For **uniformity** adding the **+** (plus symbol) along with the bounty score in the revision history will be nice.

Comment: +1 for the free hand circles.

Comment: Would make sense if you could give negative bounties... otherwise shouldn't it be the other way around? All bounties add reputation

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: If all bounties add reputation (positive) and no negative, for consistency we can add `+` in the revision list too.